# Theorem on Variation of probability distribution in a flow

Tags: probability-distributions, dynamical-systems

Let's assume I have a dynamical system $H(\mathbf{x},t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where the initial phase-space distribution at time $t_0$ in terms of $\mathbf{x}_0$ is gaussian. I define a flow $\mathbf{\Phi}:\mathbf{\Phi}(H(\mathbf{x},t))= G(d)\in\mathbb{R}$; or a coordinate transformation $R: R(H(\mathbf{x},t))=\hat H(\mathbf{\hat x},t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Then is there any theorem that says that my $d$ and $\mathbf{\hat x}$can be represented by the same gaussian distribution.
Or in other words, is there any theorem that states that the distribution of a phase-space will remain the same in a flow and/or transformations.
I checked Liouville's theorem which seems to say something similar, but it doesn't talk about coordinate transformations.

Comment: Time-$t$ shift is always a diffeomorphism. Do Gaussian distribution is invariant with respect to all diffeomorphsms?

Comment: That's the idea I am not sure about.  But if I had a time independent distribution then it should be invariant throughout.

Comment: No, the problem is not with time (in)dependence. Just suppose that you have Gaussian distribution in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and you apply some non-linear transformation (~change of coordinates) which of course changes your PDF and CDF. I think the resulting PDF/CDF won't necessarily correspond to some Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Ok,  so is there any way I can identify how my new distribution will be represented after non linear transformations, or some way how I can do the transformation to retain the original distribution

Comment: Yes, there is a [rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Multiple_variables). I think it's pretty convincing that not all transformations of phase space will transform Gaussian distribution into another Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Thank you,  I'll look into it some more.

Comment: Does this apply to all PDFs or just continuous ones??

Comment: Hm, I don't really know. I think that PDF should be at least Lebesgue integrable, but I'm not 100% sure.